# Codechef "Primality Test" Wrong answer

Tags: java, algorithm

Problem:
Alice and Bob are meeting after a long time. As usual they love to play some math games. This times Alice takes the call and decides the game. The game is very simple, Alice says out an integer and Bob has to say whether the number is prime or not. Bob as usual knows the logic but since Alice doesn't give Bob much time to think, so Bob decides to write a computer program.
Help Bob accomplish this task by writing a computer program which will calculate whether the number is prime or not .
Input

The first line of the input contains T testcases, T lines follow
Each of T line contains an integer N which has to be tested for primality
Output

For each test case output in a separate line, "yes" if the number is prime else "no"

My solution:

```
`import java.io.*;
import java.math.*;
import java.util.*;
class ex6
{
public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        BufferedReader input=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));          
    int t=0;

       t=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());

    int n=0;
    int c=0;

    while(c!=(t))
    {
        int j=0;
        n=Integer.parseInt(input.readLine());
        if(n==1)
        System.out.println("No");
        else{
            for(int x=2;x<n/2;x++)
            {
             if(n%x==0){j++;break;}
            }
            if(j==0)
            System.out.println("Yes");
            else 
            System.out.println("No");
        }

            c++;


        } }
 catch(Exception e)
 {return;}}}`
```

Comment: What it's the result that you are getting? Maybe an error?

Comment: Assuming you copied the problem correctly there are no capital letters in the required output.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out, I got the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Your whole approach is wrong, read about https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes. Besides, all these exercises assume that you use a known algorithm.

The idea is that you have an array with boolean values, where "true" means "prime" and "false" means "non-prime", what you do is start with an array of all true boolean values (besides 1 and 0), then starting with 2 eliminate the multiples of 2 (marking them false), then move to the next prime number, which is 3, mark false multiples of that, etc, until you're done.

Comment: I may not be familiar with codechef, but sieves only work for lists of consecutive numbers.

Comment: @warren, your consecutive numbers are indices in the boolean array. All you do, when you get an input value V is check if array[V] is true, if it is, then it's a prime.